# PHP copy image from file input

Tags: php, file, upload

I was wondering how you can copy an image from a fileinput to a directory.

```
 function getFile() {
    $image = "http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolslogo.gif";
    $copy = copy($image, 'img_bin/image.jpg');

 }
```

at the moment i'm running this which works fine for an image on an external area. But what if there was an image on my local server I wanted to copy?

I wanted to use a form input to select the file

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
  <label>Get file size :</label><input type="file" name="fileName" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

I was thinking

```
$_POST['fileName'];
```

would work, but it doesn't appear to.

Comment: if the image is on your local server, you should do just perform a `php copy()` or `bash cp`

Answer (score 0):

check `$_FILES['fileName']` should be there

Comment: yes i tried that although get the error


Warning: copy() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in on line 7

Comment: your file after the upload gets saved to /tmp, do a var_dump to see by yourself. I recommend using move_uploaded_file http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php to move it to you image directory

Answer (score 0):

`fileName` will be stored in the `$_FILES` array. Like so:

```
$name_of_file = $_FILES['fileName']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure to use the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on your form.
- `$_FILES['fileName']['tmp_name']` will contain the name of the temp-file that contains the uploaded file-content.
  `$_FILES['fileName']['name']` contains the original filename of the uploaded file.